# Overriding Angular ui-select2 formatNoMatches in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, ui-select2

I've got a multiple `select` in a directive template and I'd like to customise the 'No matches found' message. According to the docs on http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/, it can be done by overriding the `formatNoMatches` method.

Here's my `select` in my directive's template:

```
<select ui-select2="select2Options" multiple>
    <option ng-repeat="something in array">{{ something }}</option>
</select>
```

And this is what I've put in the `link` function in my directive's JS file:

```
...
link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
  scope.select2Options = {
    formatNoMatches: function(term) {
      return 'custom message';
    }
  };
}
```

However, when the `select` runs out of options, it still displays 'No matches found' and not 'custom message'. What am i doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally managed to make it work: for some reason I haven't determined yet, setting the `scope.select2Options` inside a directive doesn't work, whereas it works inside a controller. I set it in the parent controller and passed it to the directive's scope with `'='` and it works fine now.